# Please help with ID’ing Clover

Tags: clover

[image]I’ve noticed this clover growing through the crack in my driveway... I added it to my vivarium and it seem to be taking well... I like it be it doesn’t grow tall it just spreads and will be perfect.They're also very small, I live in California. Thanks for any help!

Comment: There are many varieties of clover within the two main groups of red and white flowers (the first website I looked at, on commercial grassland farming in the UK, listed more than 50). The distinguishing features are the leaf size, the height of the plant, and the flowering time, but identifying one from a picture is close to impossible. If you got lucky and have a small leaved prostrate variety that suits your vivarium, just go with it!

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced this is clover - it looks very like one of the oxalis varieties - have you seen it flower? If so, what was it like, the usual rounded heads that clover produces, or something else?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven’t seen it blossom yet... Good news is it seems to be taking well in the vivarium!

Comment: I also think it is an Oxalis, which is a well-known invasive plant, and it is also typical on driveways and such very disturbed places.

Comment: My guess would be redwood sorrel https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxalis_oregana